# OpenGL: glDrawElements doesn't draw

Tags: opengl

I'm trying out the Vertex Arrays stuff but for some reason the glDrawElements command doesn't draw anything for me. I can draw using glBegin/glEnd and glDrawElements in between, but glDrawElements doesn't work. Here's a code snippet:

These arrays get set up in the constructor:

```
double points[100];
GLint indices[50];

for (int i=0; i < 50; i++){
    points[2*i] = radius * cos(i*2*PI/50);
    points[2*i + 1] = radius * sin(i*2*PI/50);
    indices[i] = i;
}
```

Working code using only the points array with glArrayElement:

```
void GLCircle::draw()
{
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_DOUBLE, 0, points);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for (int i=0; i < 50; i++){
        glArrayElement(i);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

Also working code, using points array, specific indices accessed via indices array:

```
void GLCircle::draw()
{
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_DOUBLE, 0, points);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for (int i=0; i < 50; i++){
        glArrayElement(indices[i]);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

NON-working code, attempting to use glDrawElements:

```
void GLCircle::draw()
{
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_DOUBLE, 0, points);

    glDrawElements(GL_POLYGON, 4, GL_INT, indices);
}
```

Any advice? It's not entirely necessary for me to use it at this point, but it's disturbing that it doesn't work...

Answer (score 7):

The 2nd parameter of `glDrawElements` is `count`, so shouldn't `4` be the numbers of indices (`50`)?

Answer (score 5):

The parameters for

```
glDrawElements()
```

are as follows.. :

1st [**mode**] parameter is what kind of primitive to render.

2nd [**count**] parameter should be the number of elements to render. ie. the number of *vertices*

3rd [**type**] parameter should be the type of the value in the **4th** parameter.. can ONLY be either

```
 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE or GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT or GL_UNSIGNED_INT
```

4th [**indices**] parameter is a pointer to where the indices are stored.

*You can read more on this [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml)..*

Comment: "4th [indices] parameter is a pointer to where the indices are stored."
NOOOOOO! The indices MUST be stored in the buffer that is currently bound to GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER. The 4th parameter is the offset pointer in the indices array.

Comment: I was quoting the official docs.. http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml

Comment: Oh yeah, right sry. It indeed is a pointer to where the indices are stored. But unlike a normal c pointer, it doesn't point to data in the system memory, instead it points to data in the element buffer (so 0x0 is the first element in the IB).

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same problem.

Try `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`

```
glDrawElements(GL_POLYGON, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);
```